# Oozie workflow log monitoring

Tags: shell, logging, hive, oozie, splunk

I have a oozie workflow which is a combination of shell and hive actions.
The users would like to have a customized set of logs for the complete workflow. Currently we are pumping the logs as a whole to Splunk where they are indexed. Is there a way I can customize the logs and give them success and failure messages for each action on splunk? Or is there a simple way to achieve this customized logging for the oozie actions?

Comment: If you know what success and failure look like in the logs, then you could easily add new fields to Splunk using the "| eval" command to decorate your reports with meaningful messages.

Comment: Capturing and indexing the success messages is very obvious, but when I have to do the same with the error messages, it takes effort to list all the possible error messages and to index them, as this is no Java application where I can just put it to log4j. Is there a way that I can find common keys for all the actions on oozie to index them on Splunk?

Comment: Presumably you have a standardized format for your logging, correct? What does that format look like? Share some sample event data, and we can help with Splunk field extractions